# How to check textbox control value greater than zero?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have textbox that is of total score. 
I need to disable validation on the other textbox that has reading value.

The condition i need to check is if total score is greater than zero and null or empty.here is code.I tried to put  if `(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTotalScore.Text))&& (txtTotalScore.Text>0)` 
it did not work since txtscore is textbox control and 0 being integer. 
How do i solve this?

```
TextBox myscore = fv.FindControl("txtTotalScore") as TextBox;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTotalScore.Text))                      
    RangeValidator rv = fv.FindControl("rngReading") as RangeValidator;
    rv.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare the contents of a TextBox to an integer, you will need to parse the contents as a number (i.e. "42" = 42). You can do this by using the [`Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method and then comparing the result of that to 0.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTotalScore.Text))      
    // At this point, you know it isn't null
    var potentialValue = -1;
    // Parse the textbox and store the value in potentialValue
    Int32.TryParse(txtTotalScore.Text, out potentialValue);
    if(potentialValue > 0)
    {
          // Then disable your range validator
          RangeValidator rv = fv.FindControl("rngReading") as RangeValidator;
          rv.Enabled = false;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just convert the textbox's text to `int`, and then do the positive check:

```
TextBox myScore = fv.FindControl("txtTotalScore") as TextBox;
try
{
    int totalScore = Convert.ToInt32(myScore.Text);
    if (totalScore > 0)
    {
        RangeValidator rv = fv.FindControl("rngReading") as RangeValidator;
        rv.Enabled = false;
    }
}
catch(FormatException ex)
{
    // Show error message stating that text should be a numeric value
}
```